# Index independent character comparison within text blocks

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

I have the following task:developing a program where there is a block of sample text which should be typed by user.Any typos the user does during the test are registered.Basically I can compare each typed char with the sample char based on caret index position of the input.But there is one significant flow in such a "naive" approach- if the user typed mistakenly more letters than a whole string has, or inserted more white spaces between the string than should be , in such a case , there rest of comparisons will be wrong because of the index offsets added by the additional wrong insertions.I have thought of designing some kind of parser where each string (or even a char ) is tokenized and the comparisons are made "char-wise" and not "index-wise".But that seems to me like an overkill for such a task.I would like to get a reference to possibly existing algorithms which can be helpful in solving this kind of problems.

Also ,I am not sure if this question  better matches the spirit of  "Programmers" site so I posted it there too.

**UPDATE**

Another important detail I forgot to mention is that the  evalution  must be done on each input and not at the end of the task as it includes typing time recording etc...

Comment: I tried tokenizing the whole text into string blocks but such a design is problematic once user wants to return to the previous  char positions and re-type data.

Comment: This exercise doesn't map very well to a real-world scenario because in the real world there is no sample text to compare to the user's keystrokes. In a real-world situation you'd have to do a spell-check on a word-by-word basis, using white-space and punctuation as your token-delimiters. For this exercise, to solve the character-index problem you described, tokenizing is the way to go.

Comment: To address the problem you describe in your comment, you don't do the comparison of the token until the user types a character that is one of the token delimiters.  That way, the user can back up and correct and your algorithm simply watches for a space, tab, period, semicolon, colon, etc and then does the comparison.

Comment: I agree with Tim.  This sounds like you're designing a typing speed test.  The ones I've taken in the past don't evaluate if you typed a word properly until the word is complete - i.e, hitting an end-of-word delimiter.  Any wrong word counts as a single error.

Comment: Sorry guys , my specs are little bit different.I evaluate each letter typed at the moment it has been typed.Can't disclose the causes but that is the way it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is retyping existing text then it should be as easy as doing index based comparisons for simple text (one char representing one letter/number etc.) or you could employ the StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator as example below.

If you were to ask the user to type in the text first and then check how many errors were made, you could employ Levenshtein distance (see here for implementation and explanation: http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein). The Levenshtein distance is essentially the amount of edits required to make one string look like another.

Please note the implementation would be technically incomplete if you were tasked to support unicode with combining characters and surrogate pairs where 2 or more characters are required to represent one letter. In the latter case, you could modify that implementation to use StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator to produce and compare text elements as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

/// <summary>
///     Contains approximate string matching
/// </summary>
internal static class LevenshteinDistance
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Compute the distance between two strings using text elements.
    /// </summary>
    public static int ComputeByTextElements(string s, string t) {
        string[] strA = GetTextElements(s),
                 strB = GetTextElements(t);

        int n = strA.Length;
        int m = strB.Length;
        var d = new int[n + 1,m + 1];

        // Step 1
        if (n == 0) {
            return m;
        }

        if (m == 0) {
            return n;
        }

        // Step 2
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++) {}

        for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++) {}

        // Step 3
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            //Step 4
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
                // Step 5
                int cost = (strB[j - 1] == strA[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

                // Step 6
                d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                    Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                    d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
            }
        }
        // Step 7
        return d[n, m];
    }

    private static string[] GetTextElements(string str) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) {
            return new string[] {};
        }

        var result = new List<string>();

        var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(str);

        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            result.Add(enumerator.Current.ToString());
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Also be aware that the above solution is case sensitive, so you might want to make your inputs all upper or lower case if you require case insensitive Levenshtein distance calculations.

---

**Regarding your edit**

I wouldn't settle for (character) index based comparison because it doesn't take into account combining characters and surrogate pairs. I would build up an array of text elements representing the text to be typed out and then per key stroke create an array (or subset for comparison via some caching implementation to optimize for speed) of text elements of the typed input and compare them.